# No persistence provider for EntityManager named (EclipseLink)

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, eclipselink

I clarify that this is a school project.

I have to do a CRUD in Java using JPA (EclipseLink).

For this in Eclipse 2019-12 I made a "JPA project" with EclipseLink 3.0.3 and openJDK11. Additionally, I also added javax-persistence 2.2.1 and mysql connector 5.0.0 as libraries.

After this I configured the connection to the MySQL database and used the option to generate the java classes based on the MySQL tables.

The inconvenience comes when trying to create the EntityManagerFactory because it does not give me the provider as valid.

The mistake is:

```
aug. 30, 2022 10:29:39 AM
WARNING: javax.persistence.spi::No valid providers found.
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No persistence provider for EntityManager named testJPA
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:86)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
in testJPA.main.main(main.java:12)
```

My main is:

```java
    package testJPA;
        
    import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
    import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
    import javax.persistence.Persistence;
        
    public class main{
        
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        EntityManagerFactory emfactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("testJPA");
    }
```

}

My persistence.xml is:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <persistence version="2.2" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi: schemaLocation ="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd">
    <persistence unit name="testJPA" transaction type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <properties>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://SERVER:3306/gabrieln_laboratory"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="USER"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="PASSWORD"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
    </persistence>
```

I verified that generically Eclipse added the project in src/main/java (with the META-INF folder and its persistence.xml).

I've been trying alternatives and reading various forums, but at this point I'm stuck and I don't know if it may be a problem with the libraries or if it's an Eclipse specific configuration.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error means you do not have a valid JPA implementation jar (eclipseLink) on the class path that registers with the javax.persistence.Persistence class as a JPA provider. This is likely due to the version used - EclipseLink 3.0 switched and is a jakarta.persistence JPA provider. Try an 2.x EclipseLink version instead, or switch to using jakarta persistence (properties and classes) in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Add this tag below of persistence unit

> `<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>`